# Dotfuscator with Xamarin android fails build after Analyzing markup

Tags: windows, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, dotfuscator

I'm trying to use Dotfuscator Community edition with Visual Studio 2017 to build Xamarin for Android app.
Visual Studio output gave me error:

```
1>C:\xp\XamarinForms\XamarinForms\XamarinForms.Android\PreEmptive.Dotfuscator.Xamarin.targets(347,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\PreEmptiveSolutions\DotfuscatorCE\dotfuscatorCLI.exe" /p:InDir="obj\Release\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfin",OutDir="obj\Release\DotfuscatorXamarin\dfout",ReportDir="DotfuscatorReports\Release" "DotfuscatorConfig.xml"" exited with code 1.
```

When I run that command using cmd.exe, I have the following output:

```
[Build Output] Resolving method references...
[Build Output] Analyzing Markup...
[Build Output] Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
[Build Output] Build Error.
```

I've opened DotfuscatorConfig.xml in Dotfuscator GUI app and tried to change some options.
After I have disabled renaming in Renaming->Options->Enable renaming, build was succesfull, but it makes obfuscation pointless without renaming.

Can you help me to find, what exactly causing this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: This would be something that PreEmptive Solutions would best assist with as it's their product and CLI tool that is failing. It may be worth seeing if there's a way to increase the verbosity for this CLI.

Comment: Curious... what does the <renaming> section look like in the DotfuscatorConfig.xml before and after you "disable" renaming? I haven't played with their GUI - would rather set the XML. Sounds like a bug in their GUI to me.

Comment: @JonDouglas For reference, you can increase the verbosity of Dotfuscator with the command line switch `/v` or [by setting the *Build output verbosity* of the config file to *Verbose*](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/gui_buildsettings.html#pctoc-build-configuration).

Comment: Thanks @JoeSewell I figured there would be such an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*Disclaimer*: I work for PreEmptive Solutions on the Dotfuscator team, and am answering this question in that capacity.)

**Update (2018-03-15)**: The fix for this issue has been shipped in Dotfuscator Community Edition 5.34.0 ([changelog](https://www.preemptive.com/support/dotfuscator-support/dotfuscator-ce-change-log/994), note the "Markup Analysis" fix). You can always download the latest version for Visual Studio 2017 [here](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/downloads).

The previous answer, written before this release, follows.

---

This appears to be a Markup Analysis bug that was recently fixed in Dotfuscator Professional Edition 4.33.0 ([changelog](https://www.preemptive.com/support/dotfuscator-support/dotfuscator-pro-change-log/969)). While this fix is not currently released in Community Edition 5.32.1 (the edition shipped with Visual Studio 2017 15.5), as a workaround for now you can disable Markup Analysis. This is better than turning renaming off entirely.

To disable Markup Analysis, add a project property to your Dotfuscator config file with the name `disable_markup_analysis` and the value `true`. You can do this with the [Community Edition GUI](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/ce/docs/help/gui_buildsettings.html#pctoc-project-properties-tab), or, if you'd prefer, by editing the config file directly:

1. Open the `DotfuscatorConfig.xml` file in a text editor.
2. Within the root `<dotfuscator>` section, add a child `<propertylist>` tag and its closing `</propertylist>` tag if they doesn't already exist.
3. Within the `<propertylist>` section, add the tag `<property name="disable_markup_analysis" value="true" />`.